# TypeORM - How to remove last added row?

Tags: sql, node.js, typeorm

I'm trying to remove only the last added row. Instead, of the last one, it removes all rows.

```
this.connection.getRepository(EditorEvent)
    .createQueryBuilder('editor_events')
    .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    .limit(1)
    .delete()
    .execute();
```

I was thinking about adding `where` corresponding to the newest date but I feel it's not a good approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you see what is your program executing ? Also, what database do you use ? MySql ?

Comment: Yes, I can see. MySql. 
It seems as delete ignore the query above and create its own. However, it doesn't have a limit or order option inside itself.

Comment: Can you share with us the query executing ? If you think it is something we can read :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share it. I was hoping that someone has already done something like removing the last added row and would give me some pointers. More or less I know where the issue is but I don't know how it should be and that the reason for my question. Normally to remove the last added item you would sort it and then add limit and remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to query the last insert row first, then delete this row by the returned id:

```ts
await connection.getRepository(EditorEvent).createQueryBuilder()
    .delete()
    .where(qb => `id IN (${qb.createQueryBuilder()
            .select('id')
            .from(EditorEvent, 'ev')
            .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            .limit(1)
            .getQuery()})`;
    ).execute();
```